# Full installation instruction of youtube-dl in windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, youtube-dl

I have just downloaded the youtube-dl-2014.07.15.tar_2.gz in my windows. At first I want to tell I don't know anything about python. And I already have installed python 2.7. Can anyone give me instruction to execute these scripts?

I have already tried to run...but there is some error like these. "No mudule named youtube-dl"
I want a fresh start. Now I am using windows 8.1 and I have also tried youtube-dl.exe. And there is also problem like screenshot

[image: dl]

If I want to get worked both script and program what will I do?Any helps will be appreciated. If you give me instruction from scratch that will be better.

Comment: As I wrote in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24866842/35070), this is a problem specific to youtube-dl, and not to programming. You should therefore file a [youtube-dl issue](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues) or join us in the IRC channel #youtube-dl on freenode.

Answer (score 0):

To install youtube_dl in Python on Windows (command from their github):
Tested with Python 3.9 on Windows 10

```
pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

Now when using it, notice that the name of the Python module is with an underscore.

Because it is a Python module, use it like so:

```
py -m youtube_dl <video url>
```

Of course video url is the video you want to download

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be [caused by a limitation of py2exe](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/3065). You may want to [file a youtube-dl bug report](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/new) for moving to a cxfreeze, which should not have that problem. In any case, simply moving the `youtube-dl.exe` file into another directory such as `C:\Users\Shamim` should fix the problem.

Comment: @user2978381 Then please post an answer with your solution so other people can benefit from it to.

Answer (score -1):

you need just to put the youtube-dl.exe file in in your home directory or any other location on your  PATH.

You can see your PATH in your "Envirenment Variables"